# pybind11: c++ class method return pointer runtime failed

Tags: c++, pybind11

I tried a simple pybind11 example, like this:

```cpp
// header
class Test
{
private:
    int* m_a;
public:
    Test(int a);
    ~Test();
    int* getA();
};

// cpp
Test::Test(int a){ m_a = new int(a); }
Test::~Test(){ delete m_a; }
int* Test::getA(){ return m_a; }
```

```cpp
// bind
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(bindtestlib, m)
{
    py::class_<Test>(m, "Test")
        .def(py::init<int>())
        // as offical guide said, use policy refercence if return bare pointer
        .def("getA", &Test::getA, py::return_value_policy::reference);
}
```

then import this model in python script

```py
import bindtestlib as bt

t = bt.Test(2)
a = t.getA()
print(a)
```

run this script will print `a`'s value correctly, but encounter a error before exit
[pig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAPfG.png)

then stuck without exit

I tried two ways:

1. delete the `delete m_a` in destructor, then script work well, but I think this is a not proper way, may cause memory leak
2. debug pybind11, found that before Exception occure, stop at different place.

It confused me. I can't figure out what mistake I have made.

Comment: You don't need python to show that your `Test` class is faulty:  `int main() { Test t1; Test t2; t1 = t2; }` -- just that alone causes a double-deletion error.  Look up the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and look at the **Managing resources** section of that answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, thanks.